# Transform Affects Only Origin moves the object in reverse

Tags: transforms, object-mode

I have an issue in blender that in object mode when I try to move an object only its origin moves although the **Affects Only Origins** is unchecked but when I check it the object moves in reverse

**i.e.** When I move the object upwards it moves downwards
I tried to find a solution and all that I found is to uncheck the **Affects Only Origins** which is already unchecked.

Comment: Do you have an AMD GPU by any chance?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett No My Laptop graphics card so I had to replace it and the new one says **Intel HD Graphics**

Comment: Does this happen in a newly created file?

Comment: @AllenSimpson It happens in all the files

Comment: Hey :). This typically happens when moving origin of linked duplicates. If that's not the case, I suggest to report it as a bug.